# Move lines matching a pattern from one file to another

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk, grep

I want to move lines matching certain pattern from *file1* to *file2*. Analogous to operation *cut and paste from one file to another* in windows

**Example**

let's say I want to cut all lines containg `bar` from *file1* and paste it into newly created *file2*

Input:

file1

```
bla foo bla
bla bar bla
bla aaa bla
bla bar bla
bla foo bla
```

Desired output after processing:

file1

```
bla foo bla
bla aaa bla
bla foo bla
```

file2

```
bla bar bla
bla bar bla
```

**What I have tried**

`grep` creates desired *file2* but doesn't modify *file1*

```
grep 'bar' file1 > file2
```

`sed -i` modifies desired *file1* but doesn't create *file2*

```
sed -i '/bar/d' file1
```

If I execute both commands one after another, I get desired result. But here I am looking for a **single line command** out of curiosity and to make a script more concise.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why `-1`? No comment? One who did that should show how to solve this in single line command before down voting!

Comment: Vote to close without providing any reason or comment?! That's too much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/bar/{w file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

An alternative:

```
sed -i -e '/bar/w file2' -e '//d' file1
```

To append to file2, write to a temporary file and use cat to append at the end of file in a bash script, or use:

```
sed -i -e '/bar/w tmpfile' -e '$e cat tmpfile >> file2 && rm tmpfile' -e '//d' file1
```

N.B. For the last solution, only one input file can be modified at a time.

Comment: Only thing that this can't do is append lines to file2, it insists on overwriting.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and select a different filehandle based in a match of a regular expression when printing:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'BEGIN { open $oh, q|>|, pop or die } { print { m/bar/ ? $oh : q|ARGVOUT| } $_ }' file1 file2
```

It yields:

```
==> file1 <==
bla foo bla
bla aaa bla
bla foo bla

==> file2 <==
bla bar bla
bla bar bla
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately no success with following error `Can't rename file1 to file1.bak: Text file busy, skipping file.` I think it's trying to modify `file1` while being processed. I wonder how it worked for you and what's going wrong on my system!

Comment: What OS are you using. I have seen this error message running under Linux but when the file is on a virtual box shared filesystem.

Comment: @justintime That's very much true. I was trying with Ubuntu on virtual box! Now tried on standalone system and it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: its not appending  to `file2` for me, its just cleaning it off and adding the line to it (e.g. > instead of >>).  Am i missing something?  i used the code verbatim, only switching the `bar` portion to what by line starts with and updating the filenames of course.  Its not as easy as switching the > to >> is it?  i think that > is probably for output redirect, so not sure where to look to adjust it.

Comment: ok, it is just switching the `>` to `>>` to append.  awesome!

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` script will do the trick:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i] > "file"(a[i]~/bar/?2:1)}' file1
```

Outputs:

```
$ cat file1
bla foo bla
bla aaa bla
bla foo bla

$ cat file2
bla bar bla
bla bar bla
```

Comment: That's awesome! Did the trick. I shortened it a bit `awk '{print $0 > ($0~/bar/?"file2":"file1")}' file1`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure why you created `a[i]`. simple `$0` worked for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `&&` between the two commands to make them a single line. But that won't be more readable, so I don't recommend you do that.

To do the same in one command, you would need something that can edit a file in-place, removing lines you don't want and at the same time printing those lines to `stdout` or `stderr` so you could redirect it to the other file.
Maybe `ed` can do this but I don't know how to write that.
I don't think there is another "standard" UNIX tool to do this.

Btw, *cut & paste* actually has 3 steps:

1. Copy selected text to clipboard
2. Remove from original file
3. Paste from clipboard to new file

The 2-step UNIX command does it without a clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I like the other answers, but just an (obvious) alternative approach in case you are worried about making a mistake in your pattern and want an easy way to rollback:

```
grep    'bar' file1 > file2
grep -v 'bar' file1 > file3
```

Once you're happy with your results (hint: `tee` instead of `>` will allow you to see what's getting written to your files):

```
mv file3 file1
```

Generally I prefer perl to do substitution like in the above answer, but when the regex idiom gets too complicated and you are semi-blindly copying and pasting commands you don't understand, you're not in control of your precious data.