# how to extract specific lines from file and append it to another existing file in shell script and then delete from original?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt. I need to extract all lines starting with patna from file1 and append it to file2.

file1.txt

```
patnabihar 11
delhidelhi 22
delhipatna
```

file2.txt

```
patnapatna
delhidelhi
```

output files should be

file1.txt

```
delhidelhi 22
delhipatna
```

file2.txt

```
patnapatna
delhidelhi
patnabihar 11
```

It needs to be appended to an existing file not create a new file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move lines matching a pattern from one file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465127/move-lines-matching-a-pattern-from-one-file-to-another)

Comment: @Cyrus i have tried `grep '^patna file1.txt > file2.txt ` but this just overwrites the file and to delete i tried using `sed '^/patna/ d' file1.txt` but this just prints without the specific lines without changing the file1.txt

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @jww, that is not fair from last 3 to 4 days I am continously getting down votes from you :( even answers are not that bad in my eyes, kindly don't do so it discourages people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` to filter the lines started with "patna" and then append to file2.txt. Delete the lines started with "patna" in file1.txt.

```
$ awk '/^patna/' file1.txt >> file2.txt
$ sed -i '/^patna/d' file1.txt
```